# Hostbinding on component with attribute selector not working

Tags: angular

The goal: I want to customize a component attribute from within a directive using **@Hostbinding**. The attribute name is **disabled**.

The problem: I'm getting this error:

> Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of
> 'sd-form'.\n1. If 'sd-form' is an Angular component and it has
> 'disabled' input, then verify that it is part of this module.\n2. If
> 'sd-form' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the
> '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.\n3. To
> allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas'
> of this component.  recognized, yet it's part of the component on
> which the directive is used.

This is my directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[sixDisableNotAutorized]'
})
export class NotAutorizedDisableDirective extends RxjsComponent implements AfterViewChecked {

  @Input('sixDisableNotAutorized')
  autority: AuthorityEnum;

  @HostBinding('disabled')
  disabledState: boolean;
  ...
}
```

this is my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sd-form[radio-group], sd-form[radio-group-inline]',
  templateUrl: './form-radio-group.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './form-radio-group.component.scss',
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class SdFormRadioGroupComponent extends CustomValueAccessorComponent<ISdFormComponentItem> implements ControlValueAccessor {

  currentValue: ISdFormComponentItem;

  @HostBinding('class.six__is-disabled')
  @Input()
  disabled = false;

  ...
}
```

this is the dom:

```
<sd-form radio-group
         formControlName="myForm"
         idField="myForm"
         nameField="myForm"
         [sixDisableNotAutorized]="'EDITION_BI_CHANTIER'">
</sd-form>
```

Answer (score 1):

change `@HostBinding('disabled')` to `@HostBinding('attr.disabled')`

Comment: It did add the disabled attribute but apparently the onChange of the component didn't trigger so no effect until now :\

Comment: I understand now, i think the hostbinding edit the value of the attribute statically and silentely. I will add some css to disable the input child of the component. sorry i didn't specify that the component has a child who needs to be set to disable true.